# Using @csrf_exempt and creating a CSRF token in the same view

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-csrf

I am expecting a `POST` from a 3rd party server.  I understand that I need to use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator to allow for a post from a 3rd party server.  I'm using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Now, my view is going to generate an un-bound form that will contain fields for a user to populate as well as hidden fields containing information from the original `POST`.  So, the first `POST` will initiate a second `POST`.

The second `POST` is going to be sent from my server to another view on my server.  I'm trying to figure out how to generate a `CSRF` token for my form.

I'm trying to do exactly what I've read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/?from=olddocs#how-to-use-it).

My code from views.py:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from gateway_interface.post_handling import PostHandling

@csrf_exempt
def requestNewPaymentInfo(request):

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    # Gather information posted
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        # Create the initialization dictionary based on POST values
        postHandling = PostHandling()
        post_dict = postHandling.createDictionary(request)

        # Create the form
        form = addPaymentForm(initial = post_dict)

        return render_to_response('requestNewPaymentInfo.html', { 'form' : form }, c)
```

What do you do on the template side now?!?  Again, from the documentation I thought I should do the following:

```
<form action="/addPayment/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

I test this by doing a `POST` from a 3rd party server.  Sometimes I see the form fully generated with what appears to be a valid `CSRF` token.

Sometimes I see a failure that looks like this:

```
Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'gateway_interface')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/tokeniz/tokeniz/gateway_interface/views.py" in requestNewPaymentInfo
  64.         return render_to_response('requestNewPaymentInfo.html', { 'form' : form }, c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         context_instance.pop()

Exception Type: TypeError at /requestNewPaymentInfo/
Exception Value: pop expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Then I will eventually get this error:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Once I receive the `CSRF verification failed` error I will continue to get this error until I clear the cookies and start over.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I can see it has something to do with how I generate the `CSRF` token.  I don't understand how the process works based on what is in the documentation.  What is `c` in my view?  An empty dictionary that I'm populating with information and passing to `render_to_response`.  Ok, but how is that being used in the template?

Should my template have something like this:

```
<form action="/addPayment/" method="post">
   {% c.csrf_token %}
</form>
```

If not, why?  How does Django know that this `c` contains the `CSRF` token?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your problem, let me can clarify some things.

Django's template system in a nutshell works with two pieces of data: *context* and *template*.

When you put a variable to display in your template file, like `{{ foo }}`, django is going to look inside corresponding *context instance*, which a `dict` on steroids, to find the value of that variable.

Now to `render_to_response`, what you pass to it as a second parameter, a `dict`, is essentially the data you want to put in template's context, and so it will be available for you. The third paramater is a `Context` instance, not the data itself, it can be useful when you need to customize things.

Ok, so let's look at your example,

```
return render_to_response('requestNewPaymentInfo.html', { 'form' : form }, c)
```

Here, you made a mistake reading docs example, you put `c` as a context *instance*, not context *data*, hence your token didn't even make it to the template, and you got all those weird errors where django was expecting Context object, but only got dict.

So to fix, you just need to pass csrf token inside template data:

```
c.update({'form': form})
return render_to_response('requestNewPaymentInfo.html', c)
```

And inside the template:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

I would suggest reading [template system explanation for programmers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/), it is very well written.